# Android Button findViewByID returns null

Tags: java, android

I had three button on my main form.  I added a third. When I try to assign the button using findViewById a null is returned.

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:clickable="false">
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TitleText"
        android:text="@string/app_name" 
        android:background="@drawable/black_gradient">
   </TextView>
   <Button android:id="@+id/btnvalidatemark"
        android:background="@drawable/grad_btn_green"
        style="@style/ButtonText" android:text="@string/validate_mark_button">
   </Button>
   <Button android:id="@+id/btncheckregistry"
        android:background="@drawable/grad_btn_yellow"
        style="@style/ButtonText" android:text="@string/check_registry_button">
    </Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnregcreds"
        android:background="@drawable/grad_btn_red"
        style="@style/ButtonText" android:text="@string/registry_config_button">
   </Button>
</TableLayout>
```

This is my Activity code:

```
package uid.android.uidchecker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.Log;

public class UIDCheckerActivity
        extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button validatebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnvalidatemark);
        Button checkbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncheckregistry);
        Button setcredbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregcreds);
        validatebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(UIDCheckerActivity.this, SelectFileActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("func", "validatemark");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        checkbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //Intent i = new Intent(UIDCheckerActivity.this, validatemark.class);
                    Intent i = new Intent(UIDCheckerActivity.this, SelectFileActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("func", "checkregisrty");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });
        setcredbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(UIDCheckerActivity.this, RegistryCredsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });
    }

}
```

Comment: on which line showing NPE error ?

Comment: Which button is returning null? Show complete logcat.

Comment: what You mean by "updated Java"? Have You manipulated by Yourself? If Yes, don´t do that, just clean Your project.

Comment: Clean project and retry

Comment: As @Opiatefuchs was getting at and I'm going to say more explicitly: NEVER edit your generated files. The header at the top is not just a suggestion, take is as a rule.

Comment: After you clean and build your project and try to run it, if it crashes again, please edit you post with the stacktrace from your logcat and indicate any mentioned lines in your code.

Comment: you can remove R.Java from the question too, leave alone not modifying it and clean-build, just post the logcat for when the app crashes

Comment: I did not edit the R.java file. I deleted it and then built the project. Error occurs on the setcredbutton seton click assignment. However the setcredbutton is null after the findViewById assignment.

Comment: are You dealing with fragments in Your project?